# Callback function as dependency in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing a service in angular which extends a class. In the constructor of my service, I am calling the super constructor. Super constructor expects a callback function. I can't do this.callback because super must be 
 called before accessing this in the constructor of derived class. So I am passing callback as a parameter to the constructor. The issue with this approach is that users of my service shouldn't need to pass the callback function. Please suggest me a way to call callback function here. 
I need this callback because the parentService returns me results in the callback which I need to use further in my code.

```
      @Injectable()
            export class MyService extends someClass{

            constructor(@Inject(MY_CONFIG) private config: MyConfig, callback :(results: string, errorDesc: string) => void ) {
            //can't do this.callback
                super(config.id, config.name, callback);
            }
            callback(results: string, errorDesc: string)
            {
             //do something here with the results
            }
    }

//Non angular (Pure typescript class)

    export class someClass
{

    private _resultReceivedCallback: resultReceivedCallback = null;

    constructor(id: any , name : any ,  resultReceivedCallback: resultReceivedCallback)
    {
        this._resultReceivedCallback = resultReceivedCallback;

        if (this._resultReceivedCallback) {
            //process results here
            this._resultReceivedCallback.call( results, errorDesc);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not override the implementation of whatever the call(s) are and chain your functionality that way instead of trying to pass it through the constructor.

Comment: @Igor - I didn't get you. Can you please provide a code snippet.

Comment: If you want additional help I think it would be better for you to provide an [mcve] because chances are I did not understand the problem.

Comment: @Igor - I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: The question contains no examples of how MyService is used and where `callback` should come from. Callback function isn't supposed to be used as a dependency. The code above doesn't explain why one class should be inherited from another one. There's a good chance that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance is applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

According I have seen I recommend to use Promises/Observers. It is more professional and solves that you try to achieve.

If you need example for you case, write I will share